# How can I implement Google shortener API in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-url-shortener

I have an iPhone application in which I want to implement Google shortener API (I want to reduce my link using this). I am going through this:

> https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/libraries?hl=ko

But only one Mac sample is given. When I try to change it to support iOS, the `cocoa/cocoa.h not found` error is coming. Has anybody done this before? Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: chk this https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/URLShortenerSample/

Comment: @iTroyd23 this is the code that i mentioned above..

Comment: try tinyURl instead of google shortners